# React Native: Text and Values Inside Text Boxes Not Visible on Oppo and OnePlus Android Phones Error E/adevelopmentap(23783): Invalid ID 0x0000001b

Tags: android, react-native

I'm currently facing a challenge in the development of my React Native application.

While my React Native builds function correctly on various mobile devices, I'm encountering an issue when debugging on Oppo or OnePlus Android phones. The error message I receive is as follows:

`E/adevelopmentap(23783): Invalid ID 0x0000001b.`

As a result, all the text, labels, and values inside text boxes are not visible on Oppo and One+ devices.

I also faced the following warning messages when debugging my application on the mentioned devices.

> 12-20 10:42:52.143 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater(26016): Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenViewManager
> 12-20 10:42:52.144 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater(26016): Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackViewManager
> 12-20 10:42:52.144 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater(26016): Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackHeaderConfigViewManager
> 12-20 10:42:52.145 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater(26016): Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.rnscreens.ScreenStackHeaderSubviewManager
> 12-20 10:42:52.145 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater(26016): Could not find generated setter for class com.swmansion.rnscreens.SearchBarManager
> 12-20 10:42:52.146 W/unknown:ViewManagerPropertyUpdater(26016): Could not find generated setter for class com.horcrux.svg.RenderableViewManager$DefsViewManager
> 12-20 10:42:51.821 E/adevelopmentap(26016): Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x40000000
> 12-20 10:42:51.842 E/adevelopmentap(26016): Not starting debugger since process cannot load the jdwp agent.